# Wait for response in angular subscriber

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have seen multiple posts with the same title but none of them is what I need for my use case. 
I have an array of items, item property can have  ('serials','macs','null') I have to call a different API end point for each one 
 and for example inside 'model' there are an array of models 
 which also need to be sent one by one. *I know it's not the best way to deal* with this but it's a long story and I'm not responsible for this mess of a design .
the service code :

```
  createDevice(data: Device) {
    return this.http.post('somewhere', data, {
      headers: this.httpHeader,
    });
  }
```

component code:

```
 this.sourceDataSet.forEach(item=>{

 if(item.serials){
   item.serials.forEach(serial=>{
  //create it

  })
  
  }
 else if(item.macs){

  item.macs.forEach(serial=>{
  //create it

  })

  }
else{

  // create it 

  } 
})
```

the problem is there are other properties which will get affected by this and I don't want them to.
is there a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use toPromise() to convert it into a promise and use await.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise